# Locating KDE Configuration

Tags: graphics, directory, nvidia, kde-plasma

I appear to be having a very common problem with KDE Plasma with Nvidia Graphics cards. after hibernation, the text on my folders is distorted beyond comprehension. \

I have found what i believe to be a solution. which is: \

```
 Adding:

 [QtQuickRendererSettings]
 GraphicsResetNotifications=true

 to ~/.config/plasmashellrc
```

problem is.... that directory seems to not exist on my system. or maybe i just cant find it? any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It might be named differently on you version of KDE or it might be controlled by something else in another file or in a different location.

2 potential ways around this are:

- Simply run find ~/ -name plasmashellrc

  - If this doesn't display the file anywhere else then it may be controlled by something like YaST and have a file elsewhere.
- create the file with just that entry in if it breaks the system simply delete the file again.